# Creating a working copy of an old Access 2010 database

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am tasked with fixing some bugs that an access 2010 database, written 10 or so years ago, has. The database has been functioning but has a few bugs in report generation that need to be fixed (ie: bugs are not impeding overall functionality).

Since I am relatively new to access 2010, I wanted to create a working copy of the entire database, VBA and all, so that I could get into the VBA code and figure out what is causing the bugs without accidentally sending some of the automatic emails or changing pertinent information in the data. I have tried saving the database with a new name, copying it in the folder and pasting elsewhere, and creating a backup and saving that elsewhere.

Each attempt yields the same issue: the VBA project not being readable. It gives the following message when I open any copy:

[image]

if included picture doesn't load: tl/dr: database cant be opened because VBA project cant be read, if "ok" is clicked vba project will be deleted..I have searched high and low, asked everyone that has used the database, nobody knows how to fix the issue and I do not feel comfortable changing anything in the live copy.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option you might try is to create a new *blank* database file and attempt to import all of the database objects from a copy of your target database into the new database file using the import wizard.  If that's successful it won't be an exact replica of the previous database with regards to settings, but will include all of the database objects/code at least.

Comment: Would this involve exporting each and every object/table/module/form? It seems I only know how to export a single object at a time, would there happen to be a 'export all' option anywhere? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It's easier to go the opposite direction (from the *blank* database pointing to your existing database copy).  In the blank database select *External Data --> New Data Source --> From Database --> Access* (In Office365: Menu options will differ depending on MS Access version)  then point it to the target database, then select all of the tables/queries/forms/code and it will attempt to import all of the objects selected from the menu.